# Azure DNS Private Zone Preview not working with ubuntu virtual machines

Tags: azure, azure-dns

I need help getting the DNS resolution working using an Azure DNS private Zone.
I followed the documentation here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/private-dns-getstarted-cli

I was able to create the private zone example.local and I created an A record called jump.example.local.
As the documentation tells it to do, I then created 2 VMs Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. 
Took one of the IP which is 10.0.1.4 and updated my jump.example.local record with it.

When I am trying to do from the os the following command line I get no result from my A record.

```
    dig jump.example.local
```

if I do check my dns resolution configurations I get:

```
    systemd-resolve --status
    Global
            DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                        16.172.in-addr.arpa
                        168.192.in-addr.arpa
                        17.172.in-addr.arpa
                        18.172.in-addr.arpa
                        19.172.in-addr.arpa
                        20.172.in-addr.arpa
                        21.172.in-addr.arpa
                        22.172.in-addr.arpa
                        23.172.in-addr.arpa
                        24.172.in-addr.arpa
                        25.172.in-addr.arpa
                        26.172.in-addr.arpa
                        27.172.in-addr.arpa
                        28.172.in-addr.arpa
                        29.172.in-addr.arpa
                        30.172.in-addr.arpa
                        31.172.in-addr.arpa
                        corp
                        d.f.ip6.arpa
                        home
                        internal
                        intranet
                        lan
                        local
                        private
                        test

    Link 2 (eth0)
        Current Scopes: DNS
        LLMNR setting: yes
    MulticastDNS setting: no
        DNSSEC setting: no
        DNSSEC supported: no
            DNS Servers: 168.63.129.16
            DNS Domain: xqelsdawdufutaole0y2mhw4zb.vx.internal.cloudapp.net
```

If I use directly in dig the dns servers pointed out by my dns config from the vm, it finds the desired A record.

```
    dig @168.63.129.16 jump.example.local 

    ; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.1-Ubuntu <<>> @168.63.129.16 jump.example.local
    ; (1 server found)
    ;; global options: +cmd
    ;; Got answer:
    ;; WARNING: .local is reserved for Multicast DNS
    ;; You are currently testing what happens when an mDNS query is leaked to DNS
    ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 62699
    ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

    ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
    ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
    ; COOKIE: 4681bec0bce6fa9e (echoed)
    ;; QUESTION SECTION:
    ;jump.example.local.        IN  A

    ;; ANSWER SECTION:
    jump.example.local. 2042    IN  A   10.0.1.4

    ;; Query time: 1 msec
    ;; SERVER: 168.63.129.16#53(168.63.129.16)
    ;; WHEN: Mon Aug 27 16:11:54 UTC 2018
    ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 76
```

I tried rebooting the VM I am trying to inject the configuration within netplan.
But it doesn't seem to catch up the dns server to use.

the netplan configuration file

```
    # /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
    network:
        version: 2
        ethernets:
            ephemeral:
                dhcp4: true
                match:
                    driver: hv_netvsc
                    name: '!eth0'
                optional: true
            hotpluggedeth0:
                dhcp4: true
                match:
                    driver: hv_netvsc
                    name: 'eth0'
                nameservers:
                    addresses: [168.63.129.16]
                    search: [example.local]
```

It looks to me that the ubuntu os is not able to catch that the example.local zone should be forwarded to Azure DNS.

**Update #1**

I though of using another TLD which doesn't exist or is not part of the list the command line `systemd-resolve --status` returns and I used `.xyz` instead and this time it worked out without any problem. So it seems to me that I need to figure out the proper netplan configuration to force `example.local` to be searched against the proper nameserver and not the 127.0.0.53:53 dns name resolver which is started by the `systemd-resolve` service.

**Update #2**

Here is the configuration file `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`.

```
    # This file is generated from information provided by
    # the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
    # To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
    # /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
    # network: {config: disabled}
    network:
        version: 2
        ethernets:
            eth0:
                dhcp4: true
                match:
                    macaddress: 00:0d:3a:f4:5a:99
                set-name: eth0
                nameservers:
                    addresses: [168.63.129.16]
                    search: [example.local]
```

Once you edited the file and applied the command line `sudo netplan apply` it works. I also tried a reboot and the configurations is kept in place. Thanks to @nancy-xiong-msft for the tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have figured it out. I also test this using Ubuntu LTS 16 and Ubuntu LTS 18.04. The same scenario of `dig vm01.contoso.local` without result happened in Ubuntu LTS 18.04. However, It did work in Ubuntu LTS 16. I think this is because of the way Ubuntu manages network interfaces has completely changed.

Also, I add followings to netplan configuration

```
nameservers:
                    addresses: [168.63.129.16]
                    search: [contoso.local]
```

Then, run the `sudo netplan apply`, It is working now.

[image]

Ref: [Configure Static IP Addresses On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server](https://websiteforstudents.com/configure-static-ip-addresses-on-ubuntu-18-04-beta/)

Comment: @nancy-xiong-msft could you paste your netplan config and in which file did you set the search domain. I have 50-cloud-init.yaml and 90-hotplug-azure.yaml under /etc/netplan. Thanks

Comment: Forget my last comment I saw in the screenshot you edited the 50-cloud-init.yaml file. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that it helps.

Comment: This solution helped me. Thanks